# bash read -s not working when combined with -t?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script problem. I am doing while loop and inside this while loop I would like to read with timeout and if input is "q" leave while loop, but I would like to hide input("q").

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ "$input" != "q" ]]; do
    read -s -t 0.1 -n 1 input
done
```

I know that -s is supose to hide that but when I combine it with -t 0.1 it doesn't work. Although -s combined with -n works. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You need to press `q <ENTER>` in the 0.1 seconds, which is gonna be pretty hard to do. `-n 1` removes the need to press `<ENTER>`

Comment: Thank you i get your point. I changed timeout to 3 and now it's working.

Comment: Backtick-based code highlighting is meant for stretches of less than a line. Use four-space indents (or select your multi-line region and click the `{}` button in the editor) for longer stretches.

Comment: That said... is there actually a question left here? This seems to have been based on a misconception, and I'm not sure that the way it was resolved is helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm still learning about stack overflow, because I'm new here. I apologize for misunderstanding.